# C++: warning: C4930: prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2008, declaration, compiler-warnings

I have a class that **does not have** a default constructor, I created a variable without giving parameters by mistake, but instead of a nice compiler error, I got a linker error, where I couldn't find the line of code that was causing it.

In the end, I managed to find the code that caused this, and only then I noticed that I was getting this warning:

```
C++: warning: C4930: prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

What's weird is when I changed the code from:

```
MyClass foo();
```

to

```
MyClass foo;
```

I did get a compiler error.

Can someone explain to me why the compiler suddenly started acting strange, is it a bug or something?

Comment: `MyClass foo();` is a function declaration

Comment: @jrok I thought you can't have nested functions in C++?

Comment: @sashoalm You can have function *declarations* inside of functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This

```
MyClass foo();
```

is a function declaration that has return type MyClass and does not accept arguments..

This

```
MyClass foo;
```

is an object definition. As your class MyClass has no the default constructor the compiler issues an error.

Comment: "does not accept argument" is not true. `MyClass foo();` accepts an infinite number of arguments. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/47693/1767861

Comment: You are wrong. The function does not accept arguments. it is not C. it is C++. So the meaning of empty parentheses is different in C and C++.