# C++ function definition and variable declaration mismatch?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

Consider this very simple code:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& foo ) {}
}; 

int main()
{
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    Bar bar( std::shared_ptr<Foo>( foo ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Why does Visual Studio reports

```
warning C4930: 'Bar bar(std::shared_ptr<Foo>)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

and there is no `bar` object created...how can this line `Bar bar( std::shared_ptr<Foo>( foo ) );` be interpreted as a function definition?

I checked [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) and also [C++: warning: C4930: prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264530/c-warning-c4930-prototyped-function-not-called-was-a-variable-definition-i), but I feel my problem is different here as I did not use the syntax `Foo()` nor `Bar()`.

Edit: Note that it successfully compiles:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
std::shared_ptr<Foo> fooPtr( foo );
Bar bar( fooPtr );
```

Comment: C++'s most vexing parse.

Comment: @眠りネロク  no, gcc compiles it

Comment: @RichardHodges so does MSVC, it's only a warning. 眠りネロク is correct.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, it's a correct program. Which doesn't do what was almost certainly intended (the `Bar` constructor will never be called) because of the Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: Moreover, with the idea you had, the shared pointer is destroyed at the next line, disalocating the resource, and making your object failing (probably).

Comment: @Caduchon: That was just to isolate the example in an MCVE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue is about [C++'s most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The statement:

```
Bar bar( std::shared_ptr<Foo>( foo ) );
```

declares a function called `bar` that returns `Bar` and takes an argument called `foo` of type `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.

The innermost parenthesis have no effect. It is as if you would have written the following:

```
Bar bar( std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo);
```

---

Assuming C++11 (since you are already using `std::shared_ptr`) you could use the *brace syntax* instead of *parenthesis*:

```
Bar bar(std::shared_ptr<Foo>{foo});
```

This would actually construct an object `bar` of type `Bar`, since the statement above can't be interpreted as a declaration because of the braces.

Comment: You mean it's equivalent to `Bar bar( std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo );`?

Comment: Correct, but could be a better answer if you had an explanation or link about the Most Vexing Parse and offered a solution.

Comment: A possible C++98 or TR1 solution is to use double parentheses after the intended variable name. A parameter name can be enclosed in gratuituous parentheses, as you pointed out, but not the whole parameter list, even if it contains only one parameter declaration. So, e.g.: ``Bar bar((std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo)))``. Not very readable though…