# Class don't work in c++ project when created in other files

Tags: c++

I made a class in a .cpp and a .h file with in the same project, and then I tried to make a calculating code. I made an object for it, with the name "co". I then tried to build it and run the file, and it showed nothing. Why is that happening and how can I try to fix it?
The code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "CalculatorClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  calculatorClass co ();

}
```

calculatorClass.cpp

```
#include "calculatorClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
calculatorClass :: calculatorClass ()
{

int x = 25;
int y = 37;
int z = 51;
int a = 14;
int b = 63;
int c = 75;
cout << x * y * z * a * b * c ;

}
```

calculatorClass.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATORCLASS_H
#define CALCULATORCLASS_H


class calculatorClass
{
    public:
        calculatorClass (int hello);

        calculatorClass();

    protected:

    private:
};

#endif // CALCULATORCLASS_H
```

Thanks!

Comment: `calculatorClass co ();` is a declaration of a function named `co` that takes no parameters and returns a `calculatorClass`. No instance of `calculatorClass` is created in your program. Make it `calculatorClass co;`

Comment: Related: [https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/)

Comment: Your code uses class contructors as if they are functions. Just write a function if that is what you want, there is no point in using a class in the way that you are.

Comment: @john, I changed it a bit maybe he is just trying to understand constructors better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a constructor.

So the first thing to do is look at your `calculatorClass.h`. You need to change it to look like this because a constructor is a member function that has the same name as the class.

```
#ifndef CALCULATORCLASS_H
#define CALCULATORCLASS_H


class calculatorClass
{
public:
    calculatorClass(); //Constructor.

protected:

private:
};
#endif // CALCULATORCLASS_H
```

Then in your `calculatorClass.cpp` you will need to change it to this.The function header of a constructor's external definitions takes a form like this:

`Classname::Classname(Parameters)`

```
#include "calculatorClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
   calculatorClass::calculatorClass() // Changed.
{

    int x = 25;
    int y = 37;
    int z = 51;
    int a = 14;
    int b = 63;
    int c = 75;
    cout << x * y * z * a * b * c;

}
```

Then in your `main.cpp` file you are going to define an instance of the class `calculatorClass` which I did and named it `calc`. Now, the function `calculatorClass` is automatically called in `main()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "CalculatorClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    calculatorClass Calc; // Define a calculatorClass object
    return 0;
}
```

Just a heads up, when you use `int`s they only hold 32 bits. So with all these large numbers you are trying to multiplying will roll over to a large negative value and you will not get the correct answer.

You might want to use `long long int`.

Comment: You should include explanations of what you changed and why those changes were needed.

Comment: @Genoc You don't necessarily invoke the ctor by `calculatorClass Calc;` If you run valgrind on such a code, the object may appear uninitialized!

Answer (score 0):

change **calculatorClass co ()**; **to calculatorClass co**. This will work. The explanation is as the following question - [C++: warning: C4930: prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264530/c-warning-c4930-prototyped-function-not-called-was-a-variable-definition-i).

By calling calculatorClass co (); you are not creating an object; you are declaring a function.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in the code, that the following line is interpreted differently than you think:

```
calculatorClass calc();
```

This line is interpreted as a declaration of a ***function prototype*** instead of creating a new object of `calculatorClass`. This is known as the ***most vexing parse*** as noted in the comments.

There **is** a way to declare and initialize an object in a similar fashion:

```
calculatorClass calc{};
```

Notice that ***I have used {} and not ()*** ! This was introduced in order to avoid this vexing parsing of the code.

In addition, I want to comment about some other bad habits in the code:

1. Using `using namespace std;` is a bad habit, which causes *name pollution* and may cause bugs with name ambiguity, and in the worst case related to unexpected functions being called!
2. Class names **always** start with a capital letter - `calculatorClass` should be `Calculator` (we know that it is a class, thus class **shouldn't** appear in the name!).
3. There is no need in the `protected` and `private` modifiers here.