# Why conflicting types for function is giving error in Clang?

Tags: c, clang

[image]

I have seen a similar question like this on this site, and everyone basically said to change the function's name that was in conflict with `stdio.h`.

However, I have changed every function's name multiple times and it still gives me this error. But why?

Comment: Thank you gsamaras, I changed it and it works perfectly now. And sorry about the ignorance of the format, this is my first time using this site.

Comment: You are welcome! Well, I gave you an upvote, in the hope that you do better next time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Never post the code in the image**.

The problem is that you call functions that `main()` hasn't seen before, so do:

```
float getCelcious(void);

int main(void) {
  ...
}

float getCelcious(void) {
  ...
}
```

Take a look here please: [Function Declaration and Function Prototypes](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html).

Comment: You should declare the function as `float getCelcious(void)`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20843829

Comment: @AlokSinghal thanks. It's funny how I did that for `main()`, but not for the other function, sorry!